# Query is taking different time in every execution in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, time

I have a table in a SQL Server database. It has 5 rows only. When I'm running one query like

```
select * from Table
```

sometimes it takes 0 sec, sometimes it takes 5 sec, sometimes 10 sec, etc. and sometimes it just keep on executing and gives an error like

> A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host.)

What can be the issue? I am just optimizing all my queries. But it is not taking fix time, how can I come to know that how much time it is taking? My site is opening in 2 sec, 10 sec, 2 min

Comment: Could you please post your connection string and the code where you create the SqlConnection and execute the Sql.

Comment: @asawyer server is hosted on godaddy

Comment: @MennanKara This problem is not within code,i am executing query in sql which is taking different time in sql itself

Comment: Problem might be in the code, see Jon Skeet's well written answer about connections.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like *either* you've got a very flaky connection between your server and the database, or perhaps you're not managing your database connections properly (closing them via `using` statements) and you're often waiting for other connections to time out before the next query is run.

Comment: i am not utilizing using statement for connection , but i am closing the connection as soon as i execute any query.